# Afex does not give me all p-values of all parameters. What should I do?

Tags: r, p-value, lme4-nlme

I have installed the package afex with this formula:

```
x <- mixed(duration ~ (1|item) + (1+color|speaker) + group*color*sex, data=data1.frame,REML=FALSE,type=2,method=c("KR"))
```

The formula gave me this:

```
Fitting 10 (g)lmer() models:
[..........]
Obtaining 7 p-values:
[Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list
In addition: Warning message:
In mixed(duration ~ (1 | item) + (1 + color | speaker) + group *  :
  Implementation of Type 2 method not unproblematic.
  Check documentation or use car::Anova (Wald tests).
```

> x

```
               Effect stat ndf    ddf F.scaling p.value
1               group 1.61   2  35.74      0.98     .21
2               color 0.04   2  17.04      1.00     .96
3                 sex 9.71   1  66.83      1.00    .003
4         group:color 0.20   4  36.56      0.97     .93
5           group:sex 3.30   2 170.83      1.00     .04
6           color:sex 0.31   2  63.48      0.98     .73
7     group:color:sex 1.06   4 193.57      0.99     .38
```

Could I ask how I can get p values for all parameters?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software use.

Comment: Sorry Nick Cox. Could I ask which group it should belong to?

Comment: I believe there *is* a statistical question here.  It may come down to this: What do you mean by "all parameters"? What exactly do you think is missing from the output?  Could you also please explain the inconsistency between your first formula and the output? The formula concerns variables like `item`, `vowel`, `speaker`, and `sex` whereas the output involves `color` and `group` but not `vowel` or `speaker`.

Comment: I think you might want pairwise comparisons (i.e., post-hoc tests) as implemented in package multcomp. However, I've already told you today, you need a precicely stated statistical hypothesis if you ask for p-values.

Comment: Sorry whuber for this confusion. I've corrected the first formula then. / Roland, I still do not understand how hypothesis will help with p-values. I thought we can just put the model in some functions in package, and it will run for us. Do I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Do you know what a p-value actually *means*?

Comment: umm, I think it is the value telling significant of effects in the model, isn't it?

Comment: Do you know what "significant" means (in statistics)?

Comment: err... it means that factors is important for the data.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And failing to understand what p-values mean is the root of one of your problems. Study this.